# Can an external stimulus change the way your dream ends?

Tags: dreams

I sometimes have the experience that because of a thunder or some other kind of loud sound my dream ends in a way that seems to match with the loud sound. For example, the loud sound of a nearby thunder translates to something making a loud noise in your dream, after which you wake up.

Comment: This is a well documented phenomenon - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream#Incorporation_of_reality: "Dream incorporation is a phenomenon whereby an actual sensation, such as environmental sounds, is incorporated into dreams, such as hearing a phone ringing in a dream while it is ringing in reality or dreaming of urination while wetting the bed."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know any scientific evidence of it, but I personally have experienced it many times. I have come to think that it is due to the decreasing depth of sleep. You may know that sleep progresses through different phases. I've read that you only dream during the light sleep phases , or at least you remember to be dreaming during theese phases.
Hearing sound doesn't affect the end of your dream , your brain reacts to the sound with including it in it's own way to your dream at anytime , you just think it's the end of the dream because in that case it wakes you up but your brain does this all night long !

I've already head my alarm ringing in my dreams and it took me several minutes to find out it was realy time to awke up , and not just a background music !

Sorry if it's not scientific enough for you but it seems pretty "normal" to me ^^

**EDIT :** It seems like people are still trying to prove it but they're convinced it's true : [Check this studies results](http://eprints.lincoln.ac.uk/17791/1/17791%2015754-39669-4-PB.pdf)

During the study they observed an impact but due to their lack of technical language the subjects couldn't describe with enough details the impact of internal stimuli on their dream , but new tests will be done with subjects trained with technical language.

Comment: what do you mean with 'deepless' and by 'low-level sleep'. Your answer may make sense, but try to write intelligible english. Try using google translate to find proper wording for crucial terms. The deepless and low-level sleep are critical for your answer and I don't understand where you're heading at

Comment: I started editing your answer, but it doesn't make much sense from the point where you start talking about deepless.

Comment: i've changed things in my answer , thanks for pointing what was wrong !

Comment: I've also experienced this as well, but it wouls be really great to have some sort of research citation here.

Comment: Thank you for adding the linked paper. Makes the answer better already. To absolutely finish it, a brief description of that paper (or relevant quotes from the text) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Done , thanks for helping the answers to be better ! :)

Comment: @AlexandreAudin-I've had the experience with my clock radio too!

Comment: @descheleschilder I'm not a special snowflake , i'm pretty sure it's a common experience ^^

Comment: @Alexandre Audin-Yeah, I think so too. Like the well-known example of biting hard and all your teeth break.

Comment: Never exprienced this one ^^